# "Unbound breakpoint" in node_modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

After settings breakpoint in `JsonRPC.js` which is a 3rd party lib inside `node_modules` i get following error.
[image]

(1) Path is correct but i guess the debugger cannot resolve the backslashes.

Debugging Breakpoints in Linux works.

Other breakpoints which are not in node_modules work.
[image]

```
/// launch.json
   {
      "name": "Debug UCWEB - OnPremise",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/server/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
      "args": [
        "--watch",
        "built"
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "nb-tsc-watch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/dist/main.js",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/server",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/dist",
      "restart": true
    }
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "incremental": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es6"
        ], 
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "inlineSources": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strict": true, 
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true, 
        "strictBindCallApply": true, 
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true, 
        "noImplicitThis": true, 
        "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true, 
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true, 
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, 
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true 
    },
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "jest"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "**/node_modules",
        "dist/"
    ],
    "include": [
        "**/*",
    ]
}
```

###### Edit:

I just want to understand or get a hint on where to look to find the cause of the strange backslashes in the source location. Thank you.